# How to add checkbox beside a text using mfc

Tags: c++, checkbox, mfc, containers, controls

I'm learning mfc, activex controls and containers. I'm doing a assignment on containers(Dialog).I have created a dialog, when I do right click, there are system menu items like Minimize, Maximize, Move, Size. All these items appeared by selecting true in dialog properties. I have added another item "Always on top" which will be appear on top. When the user click on Always on top I provided a message box which will say "Do you want enable?" I gave yes or no for that, but I have to avoid this message box and need to add a checkbox beside the Always on top item. So that whenever user wants the dialog to appear on top they can use the checkbox.

I have tried in one possible way by adding a bitmap image of checkmark but somehow it's not working and I have less time. If anyone has any idea how I can add this checkbox please let me know.

This is the code where I have appended the item

```
BOOL CDiagDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
   CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
    
   CMenu * pSystemMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
   pSystemMenu->AppendMenu(MF_ENABLED, IDM_SYSCOMMAND_CUSTOM,_T("Always on top"));
   return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CDiagDlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{

if (nID == IDM_SYSCOMMAND_CUSTOM)
{
    AfxMessageBox(
        _T("Enable Always on top"), MB_YESNO
    );
    switch (iResponse) {
    case IDYES:
        SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndTopMost, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
        break;
    case IDNO:
        SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndNoTopMost, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
        break;
    }
  }
else
{
    CDialog::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
}
}
```

Comment: A checkbox has its own label text ... can you just make that "Always on top?"

Comment: @AdrianMole I didn't get you

Comment: I mean, have you tried adding a checkbox control to your dialog? If you do, you will see that it has associated text.

Comment: I haven't tried yet, first to try it, I'm not sure where do I need to do add this checkbox in code

Comment: [`CButton::Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbutton-class#create). Make sure to specify the appropriate [button styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/styles-used-by-mfc#button-styles).

Comment: I have added the create button but its not working